# Where to find anti-alias in Photoshop settings?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

I am new to Stack Exchange, I am also pretty new to Photoshop. I am still learning a lot. One problem I am having is, I can't find the setting to affect anti-aliasing.

I have issues understanding things sometimes so when I looked for answers on Google I don't understand the info I found. I am hoping I can get better and straightforward answers here. I know how to use the setting in Photoshop but I can't find anti-alias in my Photoshop settings. I have used GIMP and other photo manipulation programs before also I researched how to use Photoshop so I understand how Photoshop works somewhat. I still have a lot to learn though. Any help would be great.

Thank you. Please be patient with me I am a little slow due to disabilities.

Comment: Anti-alias of what?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. It would help to get a straightforward answer if you show us a specific problem you're having, possibly with a screenshot. If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Photoshop you can find this option in **options bar** (below Menu Bar ) .

option bar can be find in **Window > Options**

Only in for those tools which support anti-alias.

as. Text tool, elliptical marquee tool, lasso tool and so On.

Each tools contains its own setting.

Hope you find it helpful